# Black hole and the continuum of laws in normal space

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, event-horizon

I have heard it said that the laws of physics break down inside a black hole. I find it hard to believe that the law of conservation of angular momentum would not operate inside a black hole. Are some laws so basic that we could assume they would operate inside a black hole? And use this or another law to have a starting point to develop a new way to calculate what happens inside a black hole?

Comment: Angular momentum of what inside a black hole? Test particles in a curved spacetime?

Comment: yeah, would they theoretically travel faster than the speed of light?

Comment: I have no doubt that the law of conservation of angular momentum would cease to apply. It is generated by a rotational invariance symmetry; essentially, the idea that there is no preferred direction. Inside a black hole, there is a preferred direction, towards the singularity. No matter which way you turn, going forwards leads to the singularity and all lines of sight lead there as well

Answer (score 3):

The laws of physics do not break down inside a black hole. Angular momentum is still conserved, as is energy. The statement you have heard is probably referring to the fact the geometry becomes singular at the singularity at the centre of the black hole.

In Newtonian mechanics the basic equation for calculating the trajectory of a moving particle is the second law $F = ma$ which we can write as:

$$ \frac{d^2x^\mu}{dt^2} = \frac{F}{m} $$

This equation is integrated to give the position $x^\mu$ as a function of time. In general relativity the equivalent equation is the geodesic equation:

$$ {d^2 x^\mu \over d\tau^2} = - \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta $$

And as with Newton's law we can integrate this to give the trajectory in spacetime. The problem is that at the singularity in a black hole the coefficients $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ become infinite. Since we cannot do arithmetic with infinity it means the trajectory cannot be calculated at or beyond the point the object hits the singularity. This isn't some computational detail, it means the trajectory of the particle is fundamentally unpredictable, and as a result it's sometimes said the laws of physics break down at the singularity.

This isn't a view taken by most physicists. Our view would simply be that general relativity becomes a poor description of the physics near the singularity and that instead we should use some theory of quantum gravity. The trouble is that no such theory is known.